# Is it possible to add an XFA Field Databinding Value with iText?

Tags: itext

We are having to work with a XFA styled PDF form that is poorly designed, but we are not the author's of the form (there are many forms we need to do this for).  The form has data bindings for most fields (seemingly what is needed for iText to be able to set the field's value for XFA), but some fields are missing the field binding.

> Example:  TextField FirstName has a binding to "Use name (FirstName)"
>   in Adobe LiveCycle Designer which allows iText to pickup the field
>   when reading XFA data and allows set values to be retained.  The
>   TextField LastName does not have a binding set, but it appears to the
>   users to be the same as FirstName.

**Using iText or iTextSharp, is there a way to programatically find and change all XFA TextFields without data bindings to have databindings set to themselves with iText (without having to go into LiveCycle and find each one manually)?**

Answer (score 3):

What iText(Sharp) generally does with regard to XFA is extracting, inserting and replacing the relevant XML (XDP streams).

So you can use iText(Sharp) to extract the XML document that represents the XFA form and then process that XML document.  After adjusting the XML document you can insert it again using iText(Sharp).

You'll have to inspect the XML to determine what exactly is different between fields that are OK (e.g. FirstName) and those that are not (e.g. LastName).  The info about fields and data binding is in the "template" element.  The "field" elements define the fields.  They have a "bind" element as a child, which is possibly missing for some of your fields.
Details can be found in the XFA spec: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html

Getting the XML document with iText:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("xfa form.pdf");
XfaForm xfa = new XfaForm(reader);
Document doc = xfa.getDomDocument();
```

Inserting an XML document:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("xfa form edit.pdf"));
xfa.setDomDocument(doc);
xfa.setChanged(true);
XfaForm.setXfa(xfa, stamper.getReader(), stamper.getWriter());
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```